# How to make tooltips show up in d3.js on 'mouseover' and be removed at 'mouseout'?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, data-visualization

I'm trying to add tooltips to my bar chart, so an appropriate tooltip with corresponding data (year and GDP amount) shows up for each bar when mouse is hovering over it and immediately gets removed after.

I tried to implement a solution to this problem in 2 different ways, but neither of them seem to be working.

1) I tried creating a tooltip variable and attaching it to each bar in the following way:

```
let tooltip = d3.select('barchart').append('div').attr('id', 'tooltip');

barchart.selectAll('rect').data(dataset)
   .enter().append('rect')
   .attr('x', (d, i) => i * barWidth)
   .attr('y', d => yScale(yValue(d)))
   .attr('width', barWidth)
   .attr('height', d => innerHeight - yScale(yValue(d)))
   .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
   .attr('class', 'bar')
   .attr('data-date', d => xValue(d))
   .attr('data-gdp', d => yValue(d))
   .on('mouseover', (d, i) => {
      tooltip
        .attr('x', (d, i) => i * barWidth)
        .attr('y', d => yScale(yValue(d)) - 30)
        .attr('text', d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`)
   })
   .on('mouseout', d => {tooltip.style('display', 'none');});
```

2) And also I tried creating a separate mouse over function this way:

```
let handleMouseOver = (d, i) => {
  const tooltip = barchart.append('div').attr({
    'id': 'tooltip',
    'x': (d, i) => i * barWidth,
    'y': d => yScale(yValue(d)) - 30,
    'text': d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`
  });
};

barchart.selectAll('rect').data(dataset)
   .enter().append('rect')
   .attr('x', (d, i) => i * barWidth)
   .attr('y', d => yScale(yValue(d)))
   .attr('width', barWidth)
   .attr('height', d => innerHeight - yScale(yValue(d)))
   .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
   .attr('class', 'bar')
   .attr('data-date', d => xValue(d))
   .attr('data-gdp', d => yValue(d))
   .on('mouseover', (d, i) => handleMouseOver(d, i))
```

However, none of the options work for me. Could you please provide me with some suggestions?

```js
function addQuarterStringsToArr (dataset) {
  for (let i=0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
      switch (dataset[i][0].substring(5,7)) {
        case '01' :
        case '02' :
        case '03' :
          dataset[i].push(dataset[i][0].substring(0,4) + ' Q1');
          break;
        case '04' :
        case '05' :
        case '06' :
          dataset[i].push(dataset[i][0].substring(0,4) + ' Q2');
          break;
        case '07' :
        case '08' :
        case '09' :
          dataset[i].push(dataset[i][0].substring(0,4) + ' Q3');
          break;
        case '10' :
        case '11' :
        case '12' :
          dataset[i].push(dataset[i][0].substring(0,4) + ' Q4');
          break;
      };
    };
}

const render = dataset => {
    const width = 960;
    const height = 500;
    
    const xValue = d => d[0];
    const yValue = d => d[1];
    const textValue = d => d[2];
    const margin = { top: 40, right: 60, bottom: 40, left: 60 };
    const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
    const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    const barWidth = innerWidth / dataset.length;
    
    const titleXAxisPos = innerWidth / 2;
    const titleYAxisPos = 10;
    
    // Initiate a svg canvas
    const svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .style('height', height)
      .style('width', width)
    
    // Initiate a barchart
    const barchart = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
    
    barchart.append('text')
       .attr('id', 'title')
       .attr('x', titleXAxisPos)
       .attr('y', titleYAxisPos)
       .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
       .style('font-size', '1.5em')
       .style('font-weight', 'bold')
       .text('United States GDP')
    
    // Establish scale range
    const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date(dataset[0][0]), new Date(dataset[dataset.length - 1][0])])
      .range([0, innerWidth]);
    
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, yValue)])
      .range([innerHeight, 0]);
    
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y"));
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    
    barchart.append('g')
       .attr('id', 'x-axis')
       .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`)
       .call(xAxis);
    
    barchart.append('g')
       .attr('id', 'y-axis')
       .call(yAxis);
    /*
    const tooltip = d => {
      barchart.append('title')
        .attr('id', 'tooltip')
        .text(d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`)
    } 
  
    let handleMouseOver = (d, i) => {
      const tooltip = barchart.append('div').attr({
        'id': 'tooltip',
        'x': (d, i) => i * barWidth,
        'y': d => yScale(yValue(d)) - 30,
        'text': d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`
      });
    }; */
  
    let tooltip = d3.select('barchart').append('div').attr('id', 'tooltip');
    
    barchart.selectAll('rect').data(dataset)
       .enter().append('rect')
       .attr('x', (d, i) => i * barWidth)
       .attr('y', d => yScale(yValue(d)))
       .attr('width', barWidth)
       .attr('height', d => innerHeight - yScale(yValue(d)))
       .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
       .attr('class', 'bar')
       .attr('data-date', d => xValue(d))
       .attr('data-gdp', d => yValue(d))
       //.append('title')
       //.attr('id', 'tooltip')
       //.text(d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`);
       //.on('mouseover', d => tooltip(d))
       //.on('mouseover', (d, i) => handleMouseOver(d, i))
       .on('mouseover', (d, i) => {
          tooltip
            .attr('x', (d, i) => i * barWidth)
            .attr('y', d => yScale(yValue(d)) - 30)
            .attr('text', d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`)
       })
       .on('mouseout', d => {tooltip.style('display', 'none');});
       
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json', true);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function () {
    const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    let dataset = json.data;
    addQuarterStringsToArr(dataset);
    render(dataset);
  };  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
  font-family: monospace;
}

svg {
  background-color: white;
  /* width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh; */
  /* padding: 5vw;  */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: white;
}

#tooltip {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my version of displaying the tooltip.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

// hover events
.on('mouseover', (d, i) => {  tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);      
  tooltip.html(`${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`).style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px").style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
})
.on('mouseout', d => {
  tooltip.transition() .duration(500) .style("opacity", 0);
});

// css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}
```

**Working code below:**

```js
function addQuarterStringsToArr (dataset) {
  for (let i=0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
      switch (dataset[i][0].substring(5,7)) {
        case '01' :
        case '02' :
        case '03' :
          dataset[i].push(dataset[i][0].substring(0,4) + ' Q1');
          break;
        case '04' :
        case '05' :
        case '06' :
          dataset[i].push(dataset[i][0].substring(0,4) + ' Q2');
          break;
        case '07' :
        case '08' :
        case '09' :
          dataset[i].push(dataset[i][0].substring(0,4) + ' Q3');
          break;
        case '10' :
        case '11' :
        case '12' :
          dataset[i].push(dataset[i][0].substring(0,4) + ' Q4');
          break;
      };
    };
}

const render = dataset => {
    const width = 960;
    const height = 500;
    
    const xValue = d => d[0];
    const yValue = d => d[1];
    const textValue = d => d[2];
    const margin = { top: 40, right: 60, bottom: 40, left: 60 };
    const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
    const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    const barWidth = innerWidth / dataset.length;
    
    const titleXAxisPos = innerWidth / 2;
    const titleYAxisPos = 10;
    
    // Initiate a svg canvas
    const svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .style('height', height)
      .style('width', width)
    
    // Initiate a barchart
    const barchart = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
    
    barchart.append('text')
       .attr('id', 'title')
       .attr('x', titleXAxisPos)
       .attr('y', titleYAxisPos)
       .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
       .style('font-size', '1.5em')
       .style('font-weight', 'bold')
       .text('United States GDP')
    
    // Establish scale range
    const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date(dataset[0][0]), new Date(dataset[dataset.length - 1][0])])
      .range([0, innerWidth]);
    
    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, yValue)])
      .range([innerHeight, 0]);
    
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y"));
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
    
    barchart.append('g')
       .attr('id', 'x-axis')
       .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${innerHeight})`)
       .call(xAxis);
    
    barchart.append('g')
       .attr('id', 'y-axis')
       .call(yAxis);
    /*
    const tooltip = d => {
      barchart.append('title')
        .attr('id', 'tooltip')
        .text(d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`)
    } 
  
    let handleMouseOver = (d, i) => {
      const tooltip = barchart.append('div').attr({
        'id': 'tooltip',
        'x': (d, i) => i * barWidth,
        'y': d => yScale(yValue(d)) - 30,
        'text': d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`
      });
    }; */
  
    // let tooltip = d3.select('barchart').append('div').attr('id', 'tooltip');
    
    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div") 
    .attr("class", "tooltip")    
    .style("opacity", 0);
    
    barchart.selectAll('rect').data(dataset)
       .enter().append('rect')
       .attr('x', (d, i) => i * barWidth)
       .attr('y', d => yScale(yValue(d)))
       .attr('width', barWidth)
       .attr('height', d => innerHeight - yScale(yValue(d)))
       .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
       .attr('class', 'bar')
       .attr('data-date', d => xValue(d))
       .attr('data-gdp', d => yValue(d))
       //.append('title')
       //.attr('id', 'tooltip')
       //.text(d => `${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`);
       //.on('mouseover', d => tooltip(d))
       //.on('mouseover', (d, i) => handleMouseOver(d, i))
       .on('mouseover', (d, i) => {  tooltip.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);  
            tooltip.html(`${textValue(d)} \n$${yValue(d)} Billion`).style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px").style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px");
       })
       .on('mouseout', d => {
       tooltip.transition() .duration(500) .style("opacity", 0);
       });
       
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json', true);
  request.send();
  request.onload = function () {
    const json = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    let dataset = json.data;
    addQuarterStringsToArr(dataset);
    render(dataset);
  };  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(128,128,128);
  font-family: monospace;
}

svg {
  background-color: white;
  /* width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh; */
  /* padding: 5vw;  */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: white;
}

#tooltip {
  background-color: red;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

Comment: @SpirilOfDragon Do you know how do I show the tooltip content in a div? Basically I want to show a div on hover and not tooltip.